# How to prevent GPG from showing its head text

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

Can any one know how to delete the head text  of gpg about license when we launch it. For example
gpg2 --delete keyname

gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.14; Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law

Thanks

Comment: Read the man. Use `-q`

Comment: `-q`/`--quite` does not remove the copyright message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man gpg`:

```
   --no-greeting
          Suppress the initial copyright message.
```